# RxJS cancel overlapping events and delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

How to delay 300ms and take only last event from `mouseLeave` event stream Observable in RxJS? I wanted to take latest event only and delay it to 300 milli seconds then fire a method.

```
class MouseOverComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {menuIsOpen: false}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mouseLeave$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.mouseDiv, "mouseleave")
      .delay(300)
      .throttleTime(300)
      .subscribe(() => /* here I want to hide the div */);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     this.mouseLeave$.unsubscribe();
  }

  menuToggle = e => {
    e && e.preventDefault()
    let {menuIsOpen} = this.state
    menuIsOpen = !menuIsOpen
    this.setState({menuIsOpen, forceState: true})
  }

  render() {
    // const menuStateClass = ... resolving className with state
    return (
      <div ref={(ref) => this.mouseDiv = ref}>
          Move the mouse and look at the console...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but its not working its firing previous events also. Its hiding and showing uncontrollable while i do fast mouse leave.

I want `mouseDiv` when mouse leaves from the div and wait for 300ms then hide.

Comment: Have you tried using [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Add a first() and repeat() will reset your stream from clean state and it probably can solve your issue.

```
 Rx.Observable.fromEvent(block, "mouseleave")
      .delay(300)
      .throttleTime(300)
      .first()
      .repeat()
      .subscribe(console.log);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cy0nbs3x/1384/

Answer (score 1):

I think by "take latest event only" you mean you want to get the last value from `fromEvent(this.mouseDiv, "mouseleave")` when you call `this.mouseLeave$.unsubscribe();`.

By calling `.unsubscribe()` you dispose the chain which is not what you want in this case. Instead you can use `takeUntil` and `takeLast(1)` operators like the following to complete the chain that triggers `takeLast(1)` that passes the last value it received:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.mouseLeave$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.mouseDiv, "mouseleave")
    .takeUntil(this.unsub$)
    .takeLast(1)
    .delay(300)
    .subscribe(() => /* here I want to hide the div */);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   this.unsub$.next();
}
```